# how to run this script when scroller is 2500px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried here but I think I did something wrong, can help? 
I saw a similar code right here and just adapted.
Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scrollTop() >= 2500) {
            var bar = $('.bar');
            var p = $('.percents');
            var interval;
            var start = 0; // start animation at 0%
            var end = parseInt(92); // stop progress bar on 78% just for demo
            var current = start;

            var countUp = function() {
                // increment by one during each function call
                current++;
                bar.css('width', current+'%');
                // update percents in html
                p.html(current + "%");
                // stop interval if we reached our goal (78%)
                if (current === end) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            };

            // change progress bar every 1000 / (78+1) milliseconds
            interval = setInterval(countUp, (2500 / (end + 1)));
    };                
});
```

Comment: Your code at line 2 *`$(document).scrollTop() >= 2500) {`* is invalid - please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do that inside a scroll event callback, cause at the moment, your stuff is executed once after the document is just loaded, and the scroll is at 0...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $scroll = $('#scroll'),
        isLoading = false;
    $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
        $scroll.text($(document).scrollTop());
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 2500) {
            if (!isLoading) {
                isLoading = true;
                $scroll.addClass('blue');
                var bar = $('.bar');
                var p = $('.percents');
                var interval;
                var start = 0; // start animation at 0%
                var end = parseInt(92); // stop progress bar on 78% just for demo
                var current = start;

                var countUp = function() {
                    // increment by one during each function call
                    current++;
                    bar.css('width', current+'%');
                    // update percents in html
                    p.html(current + "%");
                    // stop interval if we reached our goal (78%)
                    if (current === end) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        // isLoading = false; // uncomment if you want to load something again !
                    }
                };

                // change progress bar every 1000 / (78+1) milliseconds
                interval = setInterval(countUp, (2500 / (end + 1)));
            }
        } else {
            $scroll.removeClass('blue');  
        };
    });
});
```

[You can see a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmGhe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are experiencing?

As written, the second line of your code is going to generate a syntax error. You probably want something like:

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 2500) {
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, saying the problem was that the chrome stopped at the terminal, however the script (effect progrss) does not work inside.

Comment: With the way your second line of code is currently written, all browsers would stop processing. Your code is not correct syntax - hence my suggestion (which I believe accomplishes what you were trying to do, and is correct syntax).